# creating/attaching vhd fails - "virtual disk provider not found"

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, truecrypt, windows-7-backup

I'm trying to setup a backup environment that I can use to test restoring an encrypted system. To that end, I'm using a secondary 30 GB partition on a Latitude d630 to run a "bare-bones" unencrypted 32 bit windows 7 (clean install) with TrueCrypt installed and an external TrueCrypt encrypted USB drive. TrueCrypt successfully mounts the drive but Windows backup doesn't accept the mounted TrueCrypt drive as a backup destination so I'm trying to attach a virtual hard disk (which is supported by Backup). The Windows 7 Disk Management program creates a vhd, initializes and formats it. It is unable to attach the vhd, receiving a "A Virtual disk support provider for the specific file was not found" error.

I have also tried attaching it using diskpart from the command line with no luck. If I reboot and use the main partition on the d630 (an encrypted Windows 7 Pro), I'm able to attach the virtual drive and run a backup. I tried connecting it to a dell studio-15 with an unencrypted Windows 7 ultimate and found it was also able to run a backup.

I also have discovered that diskpart on the latitude d630 32 bit Windows 7 Pro, cannot even create a vhd. I get an error reporting that a service provider cannot be found.

In summary, I can attach the vhd on the encrypted drive on both the d630's "main" partition and the 64 bit Win 7 on the studio-15. I am unable to attach the drive on the d630's secondary partition.

Would anyone have a suggestion?

Thanks

Mike

Comment: Is the virtual drive always on a TrueCrypt parition when you conducted the tests? I think TrueCrypt mounts the disks using user mode driver so the low-level VHD driver may have problems accessing it.

Comment: Yes, the virtual drive is on a TrueCrypt drive. It's actually the very same drive that works on a second Win 7 Pro in another partition of the system disk. It also works fine on a Dell Studio-15 connected to the same drive. I've been able to run windows backup on both of those systems against the same hard drive.